# Python how to iterate data from txt file for input in formula for coordinate transformation?

Tags: python, input, formula, loops

Beginer to python, and programming - I want to read WGS84 DD lat long values from inputfile.txt' and transform them to a new coordiante system N/E and write the N/E output to 'outputfile.txt. There are other data columns in the input file that I want to carry along and written into the new file also, leaving out the untransformed coordinates.I am unsure how to get the lat/long from each row into the formulas one at a time, one after another row by row till the end of the file. I have tested the input data and formulas and know that it works. I am leaving out the list of inputs for brevity and showing the formulas. From reading this blog and watching youtube this what I understand, I need to create a class specifying a method to process the data from a txt file based on input values and formulas included in the class.

```
import math
class Coordtrans
    def__init__(self, long, lat):
        self.long = long
        self.lat = lat
f = open('inputfile.txt')
for col in row[6:]

# how do input lat into formula?
# do I try all lats first, then longs (col by col), or one lat/long pair row by row?
# do I need a separate 'for' loop for lat and long?


#formulas

DB =Lat-Bo                           #lat from input file
u =DB*(L1+DB*(L2+DB*(L3+L4*DB)))
R =Ro-u
Y =(Lo-Long)*SinBo                   #long from input file
northing = No+u+R*math.sin(Y*math.pi/180)*math.tan(Y*math.pi/360) 
#write this output to ('outputfile.txt')
easting = Eo + R*math.sin(Y*math.pi/180)
#write to ('outputfile.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function from your formulas:

```
import csv

def latlong_to_ne(Lat, Long):
    DB =Lat-Bo                           #lat from input file
    u =DB*(L1+DB*(L2+DB*(L3+L4*DB)))
    R =Ro-u
    Y =(Lo-Long)*SinBo                   #long from input file
    northing = No+u+R*math.sin(Y*math.pi/180)*math.tan(Y*math.pi/360) 
    easting = Eo + R*math.sin(Y*math.pi/180)
    return northing, easting

with open('inputfile.txt', 'rb') as f1, open('outputfile.txt', 'wb') as f2:
    w = csv.writer(f2)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        lat = float(row[7])
        long = float(row[8])
        N, E = latlong_to_ne(lat, long)
        newrow = row[:7] + [N, E, row[9]]
        w.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, Sec, EventID, Lat, Long, Magnitude, I want to read only the lat long columns, then recreate the table with only the new NE coordinates and the rest of data. Tanks for your help.

Comment: Janne - outfanstandingtastical. I will get to work on this ASAP. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A minor snag - Traceback (most recent call last): line 41, in <module> Lat = float(row[7]) IndexError: list index out of range" Is this related to the interation ending as the number of rows ends? I counted the number of columns from 0 to 9 and columns 7 and 8 are the lat long columns.

Comment: Perhaps there is an empty line in the file. It would be good to insert a check of `len(row) >= 9` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how the lat/lans are reprasented in the input text file.

trying lats and lans together as a set for Formualtion N AND E would be a good idea.

You can use Regular Expression to identify the lat/lans if there are seperated by some charecter.